# Codeigniter 4 constructor, not able to use data in other functions

Tags: codeigniter, constructor, controller, construct, codeigniter-4

It's been a little while since I've worked with constructors in CI. I've looked at the userguide for CI4, and constructors seem to be a bit different to CI3. I've copied the code and trialled it, but I get an error message: `Cannot call constructor`.

```
    public function __construct(...$params)
    {
        parent::__construct(...$params);

        $model = new ShopModel();

        $findAll = [
            'shop' => $model->table('shop')->where('brand_name_slug', 'hugo-boss')->findAll()
        ];
    }
```

From here, I've searched online and saw a similar thread which advised removing the `parent::__construct(...$params);` line altogether. When I do this, the page loads - but the $findAll array is NULL when I try to call it in the Controller function I need it for:

```
    public function brand_name($brand_name_slug)
    {
        $model = new ShopModel();

        var_dump($findAll['shop']);

        $data = [
            'shop' => $findAll['shop'],
        ];

        echo view('templates/header', $data);
        echo view('shop/view', $data);
        echo view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
```

Advice or pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to read up on PHP Classes.

Comment: So it's clear I may be barking up the wrong key with constructors for what I'm trying to do. What I want to do is define the database query `$model->table('shop')->where('brand_name_slug', 'hugo-boss')->findAll()` as a variable ($var) somewhere else inside the class, and then inside the function controller `brand_name` call it like so: `data['shop'] = $var` Is there a solution for what I'm trying to do? @TimBrownlaw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$findall` should be a **class variable** (declared inside the class but outside all the methods) and accessed/modified with the **this** keyword like so:

```
Class Your_class_name{

 private $findAll;  //This can be accessed by all class methods

 public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $model = new ShopModel(); //Consider using CI's way of initialising models

        $this->findAll = [
            'shop' => $model->table('shop')->where('brand_name_slug', 'hugo-boss')->findAll()
        ]; //use the $this keyword to access class variables
    }


public function brand_name($brand_name_slug)
    {
        ...

        $data = [
            'shop' => $this->findAll['shop'], //use this keyword
        ];

        ....
    }
```

Comment: Just curious what is "CI's way of initialising a model".

Answer (score 3):

Well here is another answer, a bit tounge in cheek.

**A Class has**
   **Properties** (variables inside the class and visible to all methods using $this which you have read up on...) and

**Methods** (functions)

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Controllers\BaseController; // Just guessing here
use App\Models\ShopModel; // Just guessing here

class YourClass extends BaseController {

    // Declare a Property - Its a PHP Class thing...

    protected $findAll; // Bad Name - What are we "Finding"?

    public function __construct()
    {
        // parent::__construct(); // BaseController has no Constructor

        $model = new ShopModel(); // I am guessing this is in your App\Controllers Folder.

        // Assign the model result to the badly named Class Property
        $this->findAll = [
            'shop' => $model->table('shop')->where('brand_name_slug', 'hugo-boss')->findAll()
        ];
    }


    public function brand_name($brand_name_slug)
    {
        var_dump($this->findAll['shop']);

        $data = [
            'shop' => $this->findAll['shop'],
        ];

        // Uses default App\Views\?
        echo view('templates/header', $data);
        echo view('shop/view', $data);
        echo view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

To find out what **public**, **protected** and **private** and **$this** keywords do - Read up on PHP Classes... You can do it, it's not difficult.

Comment: Tongue and cheek rightly deserved - however, that's it working - you've just helped me understand where I was going wrong. More study needed! Thank you!